# Convert date in to UTC Format

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to convert the local date in UTC format.(US Format)

Comment: use nsdate formatter and try to search the older post... there are lots of similar posts.. and please post the format that you want to get.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
-(NSString *)getUTCFormateDate:(NSDate *)localDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:localDate];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return dateString;
}
```

Comment: @barfoon: timeZone is not owned and is an auto-released object. So no need to release it.

Answer (score 6):

You should set the [NSTimeZone](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *date=[dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString]];
NSLog(@"Date %@",date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2 version:

```
func dateAsString(inputDate: Date)->String
{
    let format = DateFormatter.init()
    format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    format.timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "UTC")
    let str = format.string(from: inputDate)

    return str
}
```