# How to display same time difference for different timezone in ios

Tags: ios, datetime

In y application user can make posts from different timezone and my task it to show them how many minutes or hours ago the post was made. But at the moment time is showing correctly for my timezone only and not working for other timezone.

What i have implemented so far:

```
    NSTimeInterval timestamp = [data.createdDate longLongValue];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];

    NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
    NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
    NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;





    date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:date];
```

**date.createdDate** is a **timestamp** value coming from server.
Beside the server time is of my timezone.

Comment: you are having date in 2 time zone for other timezones, which is why there is difference. Why not use same timezone for both of your dates?

Comment: i don't see how that would work!! @rishi

Comment: currently what is happening is that your source time zone is always GMT and destination time zone is changing based on device setting, when destination timezone is different, it will have different time. You might give it a try by setting both time zone as systemTimeZone i.e. convert your date from server to your system time zone and then get the time diff.

Comment: so i made my NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]; into NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]; still not working!!! @rishi

Comment: how you are storing the created date.?

Comment: its timestamp value saved in server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use standard (common) timezone to send it to server from any destination. For example use `gmt or utc` as standard time zone. now some one have post something from `gmt - 11:00` timezone and someone have post something from `gmt + 10 : 00` time zone then convert both time in common timezone first (in gmt or utc). then calculate difference and then show that difference to every one.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

> It will be better if you manage your time with UTC time.

At the time of creation store the creation time in UTC time and when you are fetching you will get UTC time just convert that to local time and calculate the past from current time. You will get the respected time with local time zone.

For more info:
[Convert date in to UTC Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893449/convert-date-in-to-utc-format)